# Python importing issue I'm having

Tags: python

my dir structure is like this

```
main/src/domain/entities.py
-entities.py has some classes
main/tests/test.py
```

in `test.pt` I have from `domain.entities import MyCLass`

both tests and domain dir's have `__init__.py`'s.

It does not find the module i want though.
I run the test.py with `python3 test.py`

Any ideas why?

Comment: Post the code you're using to import the statement as well.

Comment: I'm using from domains.entities import MyClass , but tried all variations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is main/src in sys.path? Python resolves module names by searching the directories in sys.path. For example "import ../module.py" is not valid. To fix your problem do something like this: In your "main/tests/test.py" file add:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../src") )

# Then try 
from domain.entries import MyClass
```

You will also need to make sure that main/src/domain contains an **init**.py file.
Also you don't need **init**.py in main/tests unless your going to add it's parent directory to your path and import tests.something.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not clear from what I wrote, but basically in order to import "some_module" the directory which contains the directory "some_module" needs to be in sys.path, not "some_module" itself.

Comment: thanks for replying, is there an easier and more elegant way to do it besides sys.path.insert() ?

Comment: This is just something you need to get used to in python. A few things to note, there's an environmental variable you can set called PYTHONPATH if your on unix from the directory src try something like `export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`` I usually put that in a vars.sh file and then source it. But that's not perfect either. Note that the trick above is not necessary if your importing a child of the current module so you might want to put that code in tests/utils.py then just put import utils as the first line of any test file, after the #! line of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need `__ini__.py` in every directory within the package

```
main/__init__.py
main/src/__init__.py
main/src/domain/__init__.py
main/src/domain/entities.py
main/tests/__init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It's *far easier* to utilize sys.path, but if you want a solution that doesn't involve messing with the globals, then here it is.

1. Include an `__init__.py` file in the same folder as the module you want to import.
2. Import the specific module you want from the file you want using the following syntax:  `from path.to.file.filename import MyClass`

I tested this particular method moments ago.  My folder hierarchy was one with a `main.py`, and two nested folders `domains/entities`.  **Each** folder except for the uppermost level (i.e. the level that `main.py` lives in) has an `__init__.py` file in them.

Illustrated:

- `main.py`
- `project/`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `domains/`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `entities/`

      - `__init__.py`
      - `module1.py`